# 0 rows inserted with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I've been trying to write a simple financial app to manage my home spending's and while I was writing my **Save** button code I've encountered a situation where the code runs fine but inserts 0 rows to the local database.

Here's the code that calls saveIncome method:

```
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            try 
            {
                saveIncome();
            } 
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And here's the code for the "Save" button:

```
 public void saveIncome()
    {
        using (WalletEntities ctx = new WalletEntities())
        {
            var Income = new Income
            {
                ID = transID,
                Name = tbName.Text,
                Date = calDate.SelectionRange.Start,
                Value = decimal.Parse(tbValue.Text),
                Owner = tbOwner.Text,
                Desc = tbDesc.Text,
            };
            ctx.Income.Add(Income);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Added Income ID: " + transID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I've tried to debug this everything ran ok. Object Income was filled and the Message Box shows.
As I understand, I was using the "Model First" approach to make this.

Please be gentle - I'm a beginner in programming :) also sorry for my English - not my primary language.

Comment: So what's the problem? You say that the method works

Comment: Yes, the method runs without errors, but when I inspect the DB there are no inserted rows. This is the problem.

Comment: Is it different database you're looking at?

Comment: @MilenPavlov I have a Local DB attached to this project and there is no way I could inspect a different DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is fixed and it was due to my lack of knowledge. So apparently @MilenPavlov was right. I did in fact inspect a different database. I had no idea that when built the project copies the *.sdf to DEBUG folder and places changes there - courtesy of **Copy to Output Directory** property on your *.sdf file. So as I was inspecting via Visual Studio, I've been viewing a different copy of the file.

Thanks @MilenPavlov for showing me the way :)